overriding Goodman heat pump "Comfortbridge" communicating mode
So I've just finished installing a Goodman GSZC7 two-stage heat pump. It works pretty well, but it could be working better. What I failed to comprehend before I decided on this model was that the system was designed to be controlled by a dead simple thermostat: from the installation manual:

For all cooling calls the system only requires a single Y input from the thermostat. For all heating calls (including applications with backup electric heater kits) the system only requires a single W input from the thermostat. Internal algorithms will control all available cooling and heating stages based on these inputs.

Sounds good on paper, but it seems like it could be better. For example, when the thermostat suddenly calls for much cooler temperatures when peak electricity hours end at 6pm, it first runs the compressor low-stage for a selectable duration (30 minutes max) and if the thermostat isn't satisfied (which it won't be in this situation) it kicks into high-stage. When selecting high-stage, it runs the air handler at 1500cfm, which seems awfully high for a 3-ton system, and it sounds like there's a tornado in the crawlspace.
I may be mistaken, but I feel like a good multi-stage thermostat (such as https://www.honeywellhome.com/us/en...-wifi-programmable-thermostat-th8321wf1001-u/ ) could be smarter than this; for example, it would realize that the set-point temperature is 5 degrees lower than the current indoor temperature, and select high-stage immediately. But I'm completely unclear as to whether I'm able to run the system in this fashion. The installation manuals have sections for "communicating" systems (from which the above citation is taken) and for "non-communicating systems". The non-communicating sections show typical wiring for a two-stage system with a two-stage thermostat. What I can't figure out is whether this is intended for pairing either of the components with a non-communicating type partner, or whether it's acceptable to wire these two communicating units in this fashion.
I suppose I could just try it; I seriously doubt it could actually cause damage, but I'd have to spring $100+ for the thermostat. I've tried at the hvac-talk forum, but those people are intensely jealous of their "professional" status and are of absolutely no help (in fact they are abusive). Though hvacdirect.com was great with the purchase, their tech support seems very poor (they say they can't answer phone, leave a message, and I haven't heard back after 2-3 days).
Attached are the installation docs.  The relevant discussion is at pages 10-11 of the first and pages 16-17 of the second.
compressor install manual
air handler install manual

I would expect your proposed wiring to work:
Just follow the legacy instructions in both places.
You can immitate a 2 stage thermostat by connecting y1 and y2 to the same terminal at the thermostat end (so you can test without replacing the thermostat)

Is it true that (in general) two-stage compressors don't mind seeing both Y1 and Y2 energized (as opposed to either/or) ?

yes when Y2 is active Y1 is also active  it's simpler this way instead of needing the thermostat to change-over between y1 and y2.
